# LINQ to SQL insert or update based on passed predicate

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, predicate

I want to pass entity to following code and it should insert new record or update based on the predicate. I am not able to update the record.

```
public static T AddOrUPdate<T>(this Table<T> dbSet, T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class, new()
        {
            var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Any(predicate) : dbSet.Any();
            if (!exists)
            {
                dbSet.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
            }
            else
            {
               // var result = dbSet.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
                T result = (from p in dbSet.Where(predicate) select p).SingleOrDefault();
  result = entity;

            }
            dbSet.Context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Linq code

```
 using (LinqTodbDataContext db = new LinqTodbDataContext())
                {
DatabaseLogic.Course newEntity = new DatabaseLogic.Course();
                        newEntity.Active = model.Active ; 
                        newEntity.CoursesId = model.CoursesId;
                        newEntity.Name = model.Name;
                        newEntity.Number = model.Number;
                   db.Courses.AddIfNotExists(newEntity, e => e.CoursesId.Equals(model.CoursesId));
}
```

Comment: You can't do `result = entity;`, you need to change the fields on the object you retrieved from the database. e.g. result.Name = entity.Name etc. otherwise your `SubmitChanges` will not see any changes in the object it gave you.

Comment: Will iterating through properties and setting up new one will work

Comment: Take a look at http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx or another good source explaining how EF tracks entities. But, yes, if you change the properties of an object it IS tracking and then SubmitChanges they will go back to the database. The object it gives you above is immediately discarded when you do the assignment so no changes happen to it.